# how to properly check min/max inputs

Tags: java

this is my code.

```
  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int num =0;

do{
System.out.print("Type a number (or -1 to stop): ");
num = console.nextInt();
} while(num != -1);{
if (num < min) {
min = num;
} if (num > max) {
max = num;
}
}
System.out.println("maximum was : " + max);
System.out.println("minimum was : " + min);
```

the max is always -1
and the min is always -1
neither of those should return -1

help

Edited in response to obvious mistakes, still not the correct code tho.

Comment: `if (num < min)`

Comment: condition should be if (num < min)

Answer (score 1):

there is no possible int that can meet the condition

```
if (min < num) {
```

because min is pointing to the max allowed integer

```
min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;    //2^31 - 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

the condition is not correct, should be:

`if (min > num)`

because in the top you declare

`int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE`

actual value of the this is : `2^31-1 = 2147483647`